# how to test a recurring payment using stripe test cards where the first amount is deducted but the card amount is insufficient for the second payment

Tags: testing, stripe-payments, credit-card

I want to test a subscription recurring payment where the first amount is deducted from the card but the card amount is insufficient for the second payment.
But I can not find a test card to test the scenario in stripe, can anyone suggest a method to test this scenario using stripe test cards?

Comment: After the first payment is successful, you would update the `default_payment_method` on the Subscription to a test card that declines.

Answer (score 1):

You have two scenarios when a charge can fail:

Charge directly a customer.
Attach a card to a customer and then try to charge that customer.
https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards provides two test cards for those situations:

4000 0000 0000 0002 "Charge is declined with a card_declined code."
4000 0000 0000 0341 "Attaching this card to a Customer object succeeds, but attempts to charge the customer fail."